# Mapping a section of allocated IP to each machine connected to a switch

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm-virtualization, switch

**TL;DR**

### How do I reserve a whole set of IP addresses using DHCP for a machine that hosts several VMs?

Assume I have a switch with a block of 44 IP Addresses.
The switch is connected to 4 machines/servers and should permanently assign 1 IP address to each of these 4 machines (that can be done using DHCP Reservations).

Each machine is a Ubuntu host and will host **UPTO** 10 VM guests (so totally **upto** 40 VMs).

I need to figure out a way to reserve 10 IP addresses to a host so that when machine A spins up a VM, it allocates it one of these 10 IP Addresses.
And if machine B spins up a VM, it allocates an IP from a different set of 10 IP addresses (useful so that by looking at a VM, I can figure out which machine hosts it).

The switch uses DHCP. And I can't use NAT.

DHCP Reservations can only reserve 1 IP to a machine that is alredy running. What about this case?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use DHCP reservations to always assign the same ip address to each machine.

Comment: My question is about allocating a range of IP address to each machine. Will "DHCP Reservations" do the trick there too? @joeqwerty

Comment: @RahulKothari I thought you had 40 VMs and wanted to assign an IP address to each of them?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I will have **upto** 40VMs in total, or **upto** 10VMs per machine. So I just want to reserve a set of 10 IPs for a machine. Sometimes they may be used, sometimes not.